# Computation of limit of $\tan^{-1}(\frac{b - x}{y})$ as $b \to \infty$, with $x,y$ reals

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $x\in (-\infty, \infty)$ and $y > 0$ be fixed.

Does the following limit exist?

$$\lim_{b\to \infty} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b - x}{y}\right)$$

I have been unable to give a formal proof and a result. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ and $y$ are fixed then

$$\lim_{b \to \infty} \frac{b-x}{y} = \infty.$$

Thus your question is equivalent to asking if the following limit exists:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \tan^{-1} (x)$$

The answer is yes and the limit is $\pi/2$.

Comment: Also, if x=b, the limit equals zero, and if y=b, the limit equals π/4. Everywhere else is indeed π/2, since y>0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functional equation $$\arctan z=2\arctan(\frac{z}{1+\sqrt{1+z^2}})$$ and set $\displaystyle z:=\frac{b-x}{y}$.

Be $b\to\infty$ and use $\displaystyle \arctan 1=\frac{\pi}{4}$.